# My A* program is accumulating more cells than are on the board

Tags: java, algorithm, path-finding, 2d-games

I am trying to make a path finding program to play snake and I have ran into a problem. I made this class to use the A* algorithm. It accumulates more cells than are on the board and never finds the target.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class AStar {

public static class Cell implements Comparable<Cell> {

    public int F, H, G, x, y;
    public Cell parent;

    public Cell(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Cell o) {
        return F < o.F ? -1 : F > o.F ? 1 : 0;
    }
}

public static boolean at(int x, int y, LinkedList<Block> l) {
    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
        Block b = l.get(i);
        if (b != null && b.getX() == x && b.getY() == y) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static LinkedList<Block> compute(int x, int y, Block t, LinkedList<Block> s, int w, int h) {
    LinkedList<Block> path = new LinkedList<Block>();
    LinkedList<Cell> open = new LinkedList<Cell>();
    LinkedList<Cell> closed = new LinkedList<Cell>();
    Cell current = getCell(s.getFirst().getX(), s.getFirst().getY(), t, null);
    current.F = 0;
    open.add(current);
    while (true) {
        current = open.poll();
        System.out.println("X=" + current.x + " Y=" + current.y + " FOODX=" + t.getX() + " FOODY=" + t.getY());
        closed.add(current);
        if (current.x == t.getX() && current.y == t.getY()) {
            break;
        }
        Cell c = getCell(current.x + 20, current.y, t, current);
        if (!at(c.x, c.y, s) && !closed.contains(c) && !(c.x > w)) {
            if (c.F < current.F || !open.contains(c)) {
                open.add(c);
            }
        }
        c = getCell(current.x - 20, current.y, t, current);
        if (!at(c.x, c.y, s) && !closed.contains(c) && !(c.x < 0)) {
            if (c.F < current.F || !open.contains(c)) {
                open.add(c);
            }
        }
        c = getCell(current.x, current.y + 20, t, current);
        if (!at(c.x, c.y, s) && !closed.contains(c) && !(c.y > h)) {
            if (c.F < current.F || !open.contains(c)) {
                open.add(c);
            }
        }
        c = getCell(current.x, current.y - 20, t, current);
        if (!at(c.x, c.y, s) && !closed.contains(c) && !(c.y < 0)) {
            if (c.F < current.F || !open.contains(c)) {
                open.add(c);
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(open);
        System.out.println("" + open.size());
    }
    while (current.parent != null) {
        path.add(new Block(current.parent.x, current.parent.y, Color.blue));
        current = current.parent;
    }
    return path;
}

public static Cell getCell(int x, int y, Block t, Cell parent) {
    Cell cell = new Cell(x, y);
    cell.H = Math.abs(x - t.getX()) + Math.abs(y - t.getY());
    if (parent != null) {
        cell.parent = parent;
        cell.G = 20 + parent.G;
    }
    cell.F = cell.G + cell.H;
    return cell;
}
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.